# Arc-darker theme

Tags: unity, themes

People, who use arc-darker theme, do you see such behavior in nautilus? Or there are some problems in my system?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

1) Go to [Arc theme main page](https://github.com/horst3180/arc-theme)

2) Choose "Clone or download", then "download .zip"

3) remove old version of theme (if it's necessary)

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/themes/{Arc,Arc-Darker,Arc-Dark}
rm -rf ~/.local/share/themes/{Arc,Arc-Darker,Arc-Dark}
rm -rf ~/.themes/{Arc,Arc-Darker,Arc-Dark}
```

4) Make sure, that you have packages listed below:

```
autoconf, automake, pkg-config, libgtk-3-dev, gnome-themes-standard, gtk2-engines-murrine
```

5) unzip downloaded archive, go to directory with unziped theme

6) Run

```
./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr
```

then

```
sudo make install
```

7) Go to unity tweak tool and choose Arc theme

Comment: I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)